# Can Android OS start app with different Activity than Launcher Activity?

Tags: android, operating-system, global

I have an app that is showing some weird bugs. The app gets in a state where some global data is null that is not supposed to be null (looking at the logic of the app, there is no way to get to that state). I am suspecting that the OS is either overwriting global data by itself or  it's restarting my app (or starting my app) and bypassing the initial Activity. Is any of these scenarios possible? (Of course my logic could always be wrong, but at this point I am really suspecting something else is going on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES** this is in fact to be expected in a variety of cases:

1. If your application goes to the background and Android ends up killing it to reclaim resources, a subsequent return to that might look seamless to the user, but actually happens in a brand new application process.  The return would be directly to the Activity they were last in, but in a new process.  The onCreate() of other activities in the package (such as your launcher activity) will not be called, unless those activities are explicitly re-visited by user navigation or by an Intent from somewhere.
2. A Launcher activity (ie, something with android.intent.category.LAUNCHER) is not the only point of entry you can have in your application.  Many applications contain activities which have intent filters which register them to handle android.intent.action.VIEW with a category of  android.intent.category.DEFAULT and a specification of some type of content which they can handle.  An applications of this sort may not even have a launcher activity in the package at all (though one might be included to browse content, or set configuration options, or for other functionality)

Comment: While the outcome may be technically correct as you describe, the reason is because of the backstack for the app remains in memory (os pointer).  But, when the app has been backed out of altogether, the activity that is defined as the launcher activity is sent the intent.  Again, activity life cycle should be considered here.

Comment: If you back all the way out of the task stack yes.  But if you go to something else and the process gets killed, and then you go back from the history, you will not see the launcher activity recreated.  Try it - create a launcher activity that launches a non-launcher activity and log both their onCreate() methods.  Launch, go to the second.  Then press home and kill the process.   Now use the history button to go back to the activity - result you will see in logcat is that the second activity's on create gets called (and logs under a new process id), but the launcher activity's does not.

Comment: However, if you kill the process while it is on screen, you may restart from the launcher activity.  And if you kill it while it is off screen, restart it from the history directly into the second activity, and then press back, at that point the launcher activity will get created.  To the user it looks like it was always there, but in actually it only got recreated when needed.

Comment: This is extremely useful information to me and I find that this is not documented very well (reference?). Thanks so much Chris. At least now I know I have to consider this case.

Comment: It is documented in the Activity life cycle documentation.  :^)

Comment: @AndroidAddict Can you point out where? My issue is more an Application lifecycle rather than an Activity lifecycle issue

Comment: While not certain, it's highly likely an Activity life cycle issue as there is no application life cycle.  In brief the ONLY event you can count on when your activity goes to the background is the onPause event.  Make sure you put your application in a good state when this event is fired.  If your activity is in the background when the OS kills it, no event will fire in your app.  So, you have no chance to set application state at that point.

Check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Many find the documentation a bit confusing, but if you understand the relationship between activity life cycle and the back stack, I believe you will find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Can Android OS start app with different Activity than Launcher Activity?
```

**No, It always search an activity with launcher tag to start with.**

Add your code, and be specific which global data is getting null value :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt it.  The idea of the launcher is that is defines the activity that receives the launch intent from the OS.

Guessing from the behavior you described, you may want to do some research on Activity life cycles.

Answer (score 0):

**Launcher is used to identify the activity which is to be launched as the application starts**.... so **i dont** think so its possible...